# Notepad++ : HTML Format

Tags: notepad++

Is there a plugin to set HTML automatically in Notepad++

My previous question on Notepad++ autocomplete fixed.

The problem is when I installed "TextFx Character" - something like:

happens : one unnecessary  occurs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I mean HTML5 format!!!

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Notepad ++` --> `Language` --> `H` --> `HTML`.

This will convert your code to HTML format.